# Got unknown content type (null) from reviews.ubuntu.com on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install some software in Ubuntu 17.10 version. But all the time it shows this error message:

```
Sorry something went wrong . Got unknown content type (null) from reviews.ubuntu.com.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Which software and how are you trying to install?

Comment: I got the the same error when I tried to install dconf editor from ubuntu software center

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem. First update your softwear and then Enable Canonical Partner repositories. You will do that on this way: go to Activity Overview by pressing Super Key (Windows key), and look for Software & Updates, then open it and under the Other Software tab, and check the all option.It will ask for your password and update the software sources. It worked for me.